# actionbar search will not close after search

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an actionbar with a search icon. When the search icon is clicked, it expands to a search bar in which the user can type in a search.

The problem is when the user enters the search I would like the search bar to collapse back to an icon but I can not get it to happen for the life of me.

My actionbar menu looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_search2"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView|"
        android:onClick="goToSearch"
        />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_scan"
        android:icon="@drawable/barcode"
        android:onClick="scanBarcode"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        />

</menu>
```

My search activity looks like this:

```
public class Search extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener {

    private ListView lv;
    View v;
    SearchView searchView;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private MenuItem mSearchMenuItem;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //set layout here
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_search, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle("Search");


        //get user information
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
        String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);


        return v;


}

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        searchView.setIconified(false);
    }


    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query
        //make json variables to fill
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();

        // url to make request
        String url = "myURL";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;


        //todo: get json
        ReadJSONResult task = new ReadJSONResult(getActivity());
        task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);
        task.execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }





    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(String b, String brewery){
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.clearFocus();
        searchView.postInvalidate();
        //code to execute on click
        Fragment Fragment_one;
        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();

        //adds beer data to shared prefs for beer tabs
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putString("beerID",b);
        editor.putString("breweryID",brewery);
        editor.commit();
        Fragment_one = new BeerTabs();

        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
        tran.addToBackStack(null);
        tran.commit();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After some searches, I find the solution. The `onActionViewCollapsed` works but you had an unexpected behaviour (icon jumps to left, up indicator still here...) *- this (hard) solution was suggested in my first and previous answer*, and I was persuaded by use of `collapseActionView` method. However, `SearchView.collapseActionView()` was not working because according to the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#collapseActionView%28%29):

> Collapse the action view associated with **this menu item.**

It's related to the `MenuItem` and not to the `SearchView` widget. That's why you had this error when you used this method:

> The method *collapseActionView()* is undefined for **the type SearchView**

Then, the solution is to create a `Menu` variable as follows:

```
 // At the top of your class
 private Menu mMenu;

 // onCreateOptionsMenu method
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      this.mMenu = menu; // init the variable
      // other stuff..
      return true;
 }

 // call the collapseActionView method
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
      searchView.setIconified(true);
      searchView.clearFocus();
      // call your request, do some stuff..

      // collapse the action view
      if (mMenu != null) { 
          (mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2)).collapseActionView();
      }
      return false;
 }
```

Or another might be to avoid the implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` and to do it inside `onCreateOptionsMenu` as follows:

```
@Override
// make your Menu as 'final' variable
public void onCreateOptionsMenu (final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2).getActionView();
    // call the query listener directly on the SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchView.setIconified(true);
            searchView.clearFocus();

            // call the request here

            // call collapse action view on 'MenuItem'
            (menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search2)).collapseActionView();

            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { return false; }
    });
    searchView.setIconified(false);
}
```

This will resolve the issue for sure. Happy coding!

Comment: So that almost worked perfectly, it collapsed like it should but didnt execute my search...

My code looks like this now:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cf26b36c5a22b64459b6

Comment: It's because you have the query listener twice. Make sure you deleted the implement OnQueryListener and copy/paste all your stuff (json request, etc) **inside the same query listener** where you're collapse the view. Inside the code above which provide you a query listener. Do you see @Mike?

Comment: See my updated answer above. Call your request inside the listener at the commented line *"call your request here"*. HTH @Mike

Comment: Just tried that, but it does not like the this on this line:

                task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(this);

Comment: @Mike Try to attach the context instead: `task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(getActivity())`

Comment: nope I get this:

setOnArticleSelectedListener
(com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.ReadJSONResult.OnArticleSelectedListener)
in ReadJSONResult cannot be applied
to
(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity)

Comment: @Mike, Ahh, yes, you have two parameters on the declaration of onArticleSelected method. I thought about your json request indeed, no?

Comment: I am a little confused cause it looks like my old code had this in it and worked...

Comment: @Mike come into the chat please, I'll explain: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50928/discussion-between-fllo-and-mike)

Comment: Thanks .. You save my day. Above code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 34):

One simpler way, that works even if the SearchView widget is not on the actionbar is the following code:

```
searchView.setQuery("", false);
searchView.setIconified(true);
```

And that makes the SearchView collapse after a search is made.

Comment: `searchView.setQuery("", false);` this did the trick